# Using $_SESSION on PHP form

Tags: php, forms, session

**How can I show show the variables saved in 'name' and 'email using $_SESSION only (meaning not using $_COOKIE)?**

I created this program that works using $_COOKIE but (I know) it's not really well designed. I'm just learning. But I'm trying to convert a form that collects data using $_SESSION instead of $_COOKIE. All I did was replaced $_COOKIE with $_SESSION (less setcookie etc.). My goal is if you click on "remember me" it'll remember your 'name' and 'email' so that you can directly click on a "link" to download something upon reopening a browser.

```
<?php
session_start();
    // session
    if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
$customer_name = $_SESSION['name'];
if (!($customer_name)) {
$customer_name = $_POST['name'];
}
$customer_email = $_SESSION['email'];
if (!($customer_email)) {
$customer_email = $_POST['email'];
}

//If Form submitted
//I.e. Email validation that will check if field is empty or doesn't 
//If there is no error
echo 'Here's the <a href="http://www.google.com/something">link.<br />';
//else there's error

<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Name:
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['name']."<br />";
  }
else {
?> 
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>" size="25" /><br />
<?php } ?>

Email:
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['email']."<br /><br />";
  }
else {
?>  
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" size="25"/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" /> Remember me
<input type="submit" name="Submit" />
<?php } ?>


</form>
```

Comment: Sessions are usually temporary, cookies allow you to set an expiration date far into the future.

Comment: @Barmar $_SESSION and $_COOKIE are the same only the data saved on client's end is a "token" on the former but the latter is the actual content of the variable being collected (i.e. $_COOKIE['name'] = "john" that is saved on client's browser).

Comment: you say the 
are the same, then explain how they are different

Comment: Session files that haven't been used in a while are typically deleted, although you can configure how long that takes.

Comment: Users are asked to register 'name' and 'email'. To get a download link. If they choose to get remembered then they click on "remember me" check box. If so, upon reopening the browser should just spit out "John" "email@example.com", then a download link without a need to reregister.

Comment: @Dagon the difference as you should now know is that $_SESSION doesn't save the content of variable 'name' on client's browser correct? $_COOKIE does right? Example, if you type in $_COOKIE['name'] = "john" the content is saved on your browser (look it up it'll say "john"). If you start a session $_SESSION['name'] = "john" that isn't shown on the browser it'll show a token in PHPSESSID.

Comment: @Barmar correct. I'm sorry my question was that I couldn't make the program to work using $_SESSION (whether or not you suggest to use $_COOKIE). How to spit out the values 'name' 'email' even temporarily. I don't care if it will usually be deleted. These are not important.

Comment: The problem in your code is that you're setting the session variables from regular variables before you set the regular variables.

Comment: @AmirT thanks I'm not really good at asking questions. I edited my original post.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your insight. Where in particular are you talking about? Just because I saw this form where it uses cookies rather than sessions and was able to replace $_COOKIE with $_SESSION so long as I type start_session() function. The difference is that on my form I'm able make it to work using cookies but not sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies instead. Set a cookie with the email for example, and it will be remembered until the cookie expires. If you use session, it will depend on server config but its usually low (less than a day).

Anyway, i dont see any question at all here :P

Comment: but cookies are the right approach for 'remember me', sessions are not

Comment: @Dagon I was trying to use the concept I made for $_COOKIE convert that to $_SESSION and you can make it to work that way. The difference between the two is that $_SESSION saves a token on client's browser (the rest on server) but $_COOKIE actually saves the "content" (i.e. John, email@email.com).

Comment: if you can make it work that way- then go for it, but i don't think you really understand the difference.

Comment: @Dagon sorry that was my problem I couldn't but you can. And I did google and searched here closed but not quite on my darn code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    }
    $customer_name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $customer_email = $_SESSION['email'];
    ...
```

In your code, you're setting `$customer_XXX`, but never setting `$_SESSION['XXX']`.

Comment: these two are typos:   $_SESSION['name'] = $customer_name;
  $_SESSION['email'] = $customer_email;